# How to rotate text when typing on a path

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to get the text that's typed on a path of this photo straight but I can't. It's typed upside down. I already went to Type on a path >> Options and flipped it but it doesn't fix the problem.

PS. the text that you see selected is an example of what I would like my path text to be like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select text - go into Menu:Text:text on Path - and use a checkbox "Flip text"